# Ability to Decrypt and Verify PHP Code from Server

Tags: php, security, encryption, deobfuscation

**Background**

This feels a little backwards, but I hit a wall while attempting to verify the contents of a suspicious looking PHP file on a web host of mine. The file in question calls itself `elianore-highlighter.php` and was last modified as of 30-April this year, just before my site started getting failed login attempts by persons unknown from IP addresses ranging in the Ukraine, Russian Federation, and China. I've blocked the IPs I've found and started battening down the hatches, so to speak.

**Situation**

I would like to decrypt the contents of the PHP file to fully see what's going on. I assumed it was base64 encoded, but a simple browser based `atob('suspiciousString')` in my browser didn't return anything useful. My PHP-fu is somewhat lacking as I've been primarily focused on other languages for the past few years.

[image: odd output when trying to decrypt string]

I [Google'd "elianore-highlighter.php"](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=elianore-highlight.php) and didn't see anything terribly valid or relevant pop up (at least in the first page) and nothing on SO seemed immediatelyy relevant.

Being cautious, I stuffed the file in a zip and removed it from the server, just to be on the safe side, so it's not currently in play.

**Question**

How can I *safely* go about decrypting this to validate it? Obviously I'm dubious of it, as I'm uncertain of its origin or contents prior to 30-April.

Here's [the pastebin of the source of the file](http://pastebin.com/QQAyfTJ2). I recommend caution.

[Update]

As [Max Haaksman answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31324096/1720082), the ability to properly view the contents was to reverse the `strrev` call and then perform the base64 decoding.

Also, as my comment under this question makes clear, I refute the wish to close this as 'off topic' as this is not a 'help my site was hacked' question, this was specific to the code in question, had code as the primary subject, and had a code focused answer.

From the StackOverflow tour, a question should:

> "focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do."

Tips mention to ask about:

- Specific programming problems
- Software algorithms
- Coding techniques
- Software development tools

As my question relies specifically about a code problem I was faced with, including details about what I had tried and wanted to accomplish, along with a focus on language specific algorithms and techniques, I believe that this is perfectly valid.

[/Update]

Comment: decrypted it for fun, it's a backdoor, trying to download a file from a domain (k-fish-ka.ru) and trying to exploit functions that should be deactivated like eval and shell_exec.

Comment: That explains the IP origins, among other things.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, [like another question opened tonight, your website being hacked is off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31331869/php-malware-automatically-insert-and-echo-a-script-to-php-js-files-link-to-a).

Comment: The question had nothing to do with the site being hacked and everything to do with verifying code contents and execution logic of a PHP file. Please don't mistake what caused the situation with the question I asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for starters the code when strrev is applied will switch a few strings from "lave" to "eval" which should raise flags.

You could base 64 decode the payload string (apparently after reversing it) but suffice it to say that if you didn't build it you don't want it on your site.

Hardening your server is a good plan.

Edit

You could safely run strrev and and base 64 decode on the strings. It goes without saying but don't invoke any of the code in any shape or form however.

Comment: Thanks. If I had thought about it differently, I might have realized the reversal. I've been too long away from PHP, it seems, as strrev didn't stand out 